# Format NSDate from String date

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate

I need to create an NSDate but my problem is that I'm retrieving this from a webservice not managed by me:

20141118 01:00:00 +0000

It's possible convert this into an NSDate?

Comment: in lot of of answer is available in stack overflow plz refer once

Comment: OP: you are kidding right?  Have you searched?

Comment: It looks no so hard to convert... use `yyyyMMdd hh:mm:ss z` as dateformatter. *this may have some issue, as not compiler checked*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

```
NSString *dateString = @"20141118 01:00:00 +0000";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter=[NSDateFormatter new];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyyMMdd hh:mm:ss Z"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
```